# Nested #import statements: how to hide nested ones?

Tags: objective-c, import

I have the following project structure:

- Main.h

  - Son1.h
  - Son2.h

They're not related (no father/son relationships), just two imports, like in `Main.h` I have:

```
#import Son1.h
#import Son2.h
```

If, from another file I write

```
#import Main.h
```

I will see all the methods/properties of `Main.h` (and that's ok) but I will also see the methods of `Son1.h` and `Son2.h`.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Do the import in .m? And if needed, do `@class Son1;` and `@class Son2;` if you have some declaration with `Son1` or `Son2`. Note that the `#import` don't have ";".

Comment: If you don't want them included when Main.h is included, then don't put them in Main.h.  In general, you should consider any includes/imports in a header to be part of that header, because that's what the compiler will see.  If you want certain files to only be included under certain conditions, then do not include them in an "umbrella" header that includes everything.

Comment: the problem is that I need the `#imports` in the "umbrella" since the Main do some work with them. How can I handle the `#imports` in the .m with `@class` in `Main.h` using also delegates (that are from the imported files)

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand what `#import` (and the C version: `#include`) do.

Compilation of C programs conceptually have 3 steps:

- Preprocessing
- Compiling
- Linking

The directives beginning with `#` are acted on by the preprocessor (it doesn't matter at all whether this is a separate binary or part of the compiler).  Both of these statements cause the contents of the named file to inserted into the importing (or including) file at the point where the directive is found.  This is completely language-agnostic.  The imported file can have anything in it.  You can import a JPG, if you want (but good luck compiling!).

In your example, by importing `Son1.h` and `Son2.h` in `Main.h`, you are creating, from the compiler's perspective, a single file with the contents of `Son1.h` followed by the contents of `Son2.h` followed by whatever is in `Main.h` itself.  At this level, the idea of hiding content doesn't make sense.  You explicitly asked the preprocessor to put those contents there.  It doesn't know anything about the text it's inserting, so it can't follow any kind of Objective-C directive, even if such existed.

The comments are getting to another point.  Importing in a `.h` should be kept to an absolute minimum.  The most common reasons to import are for class and protocol type definitions, and Objective-C allows you to forward declare both of these precisely to avoid otherwise necessary imports.

If you have something like:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
    @property(nonatomic, strong) MyOtherClass *myOtherClass;
@end
```

You normally would have to `#import "MyOtherClass.h"`.  However, with forward declarations, you can do this instead:

```
@class MyOtherClass;
```

And move the `#import` to the implementation file, which is generally hidden from other files.

Comment: yes, I know. Is there a better way to import classes and use them within the Main.m file?